# Format text for STDOUT in Ruby

Tags: ruby, formatting, stdout

I am writing a small Ruby script that will run in a CLI.

To improve the interface, I need to would love to add color/boldness to some elements that I output.

Is that doable? If so, and I am almost sure this is, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a gem called `rainbow` that makes it really easy to style your terminal output.

```
sudo gem install rainbow
```

After installing it you can do stuff like:

```
puts 'some text'.underline
```

- https://rubygems.org/gems/rainbow
- http://github.com/sickill/rainbow/tree/master

Comment: Times have changed, in this day and age I'd probably now use https://github.com/geemus/formatador.

Answer (score 13):

On many terminals (but not Windows), you can use an a sequence like this: `"\e[#{code}m"`, where the codes are based on [these tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Codes).  The codes must be separated by a semicolon if using more than one.  The major codes are:

### Intensity:

```
1  Bold Intensity
4  Underline
5  Slow blink
6  Fast blink
22 Normal Intensity
```

### Color:

```
Foreground 3X
Background 4X

Where X is:
-----------
0 Black
1 Red
2 Green
3 Yellow
4 Blue
5 Magenta
6 Cyan
7 White
```

So, for example, for slowly blinking, bold green text on a blue background, you would use `"\e[5;1;32;44mWOW!\e[0m"`.  The `\e[0m` resets everything to the terminal default.

Answer (score 0):

**Dear Ruby folks!**
I prefer to find the default integrated support available within Ruby. Here I've found a few, which may work without installing any gem:

```
def red(mytext); "\e[31m#{mytext}\e[0m"; end
def light_red(mytext); "\e[1;31m#{mytext}\e[0m"; end
def green(mytext); "\e[32m#{mytext}\e[0m"; end
def light_green(mytext); "\e[1;32m#{mytext}\e[0m"; end
def yellow(mytext); "\e[1;33m#{mytext}\e[0m"; end
def blue(mytext); "\e[34m#{mytext}\e[0m"; end
def light_blue(mytext); "\e[1;34m#{mytext}\e[0m"; end

puts red("hello world. I don't need no color.")
puts light_red("hello world. I don't need no color.")
puts green("hello world. I don't need no color.")
puts light_green("hello world. I don't need no color.")
puts blue("hello world. I don't need no color.")
puts light_blue("hello world. I don't need no color.")
puts yellow("hello world. I don't need no color.")
```

It works with both *puts* and *print*.